# How to display caption of remote videos with Media?

Tags: html, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I created a template for Media Video Remote.

I have a problem with. When I embed a video with CKeditor, there is a "Caption" checkbox.

The problem is that with my template the caption is not displayed.

How to display video caption ?

media--remote-video--default.html.twig :

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'media',
    'media--type-' ~ media.bundle()|clean_class,
    not media.isPublished() ? 'media--unpublished',
    view_mode ? 'media--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
  ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_suffix.contextual_links }}
  {% if content %}
    <div id="youtube-remote">
      <a href="{{ content.field_media_oembed_video.0 }}" target="_blank">
        <div class="youtube-remote-container">
          <img src="{{ content.thumbnail.0 }}" width="1280" height="720" alt="" loading="lazy">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 68 48">
            <path class="play-outer" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z"/>
            <path d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34" fill="white"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        HERE FIGCAPTION ......................
      </a>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: It's not very clear. You have a caption field in your media, so you must be able to add it to your template `{{ content.caption }}`

Comment: @ThomasLefetz `{% if content.caption %}
          <figcaption>{{ content.caption }}</figcaption>
        {% endif %}` thank you is this code to display the legend when a value is entered ?

Comment: I guess it depends on how your media is built. Don't forget to make the caption visible in your media view. And you have to check if Drupal retrieve caption of the remote media.